# Best way to edit my CMS content

Tags: php, mysql, content-management-system, edit

Hi I've built a php and mysql CMS, it's just for some news articles on my site. Currently I have a page which contains form fields and you change the content and it adds it to my database. I've not yet worked out how to add images or which method is the best. Is it easy to create an edit page where you can add images and change content on the one page.

I've put together the following code and was thinking of adding jQuery to show form fields but would this meaning saving at each time to change any part of content.

```
<div class="articleWrap">

<p>2012<span id="editYear">Edit</span></p>
<h2>Article title<span id="editTitle">Edit</span></h2>
<h4><em>Date</em><span id="editDate">Edit</span></h4>
<p>bfewg uerwgiw h uih ui  huihuihui huihui jio jio gtf ffti huoh uh fr f huih uh uifdijoj j ifodijo fdjioj iofdjio hfs hu ofhuop ogjdo ifho  fhudohu fisj iojigji gpdjiodj  fjido joijd jido jdoi dji fojgido  jifodifhdh ud hugodhu ohuh uh ugodh uduhoh uoh oh u hudo giojfpj gipjipfjigdip gji hhuidh uihfudih ufhiudhu idhu idhuih udi hu   hugreih ghe g rehuigeh gh ge hgurieh ghruei ghu eihgur ehg e g ghuriehg hr ghru eihg ruii ehghr hoej dsojfewio iehfj-i gvjl  vjdsl hv h vhdjsih v.<span id="editContent">Edit</span></p>

<p><span class="articleImage">images here<span id="editImage">Edit</span></span>

<span class="articleImage">images here<span id="editImage">Edit</span></span>

<span class="articleImage">images here<span id="editImage">Edit</span></span> </p>

</div>
```

Any help or advise on tutorials would be very helpful. Many thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you're building your own when there are so many good ones out there?

Comment: This was built as a quick way to edit articles, rather than impliment a whole CMS system which I don't currently want I made a simple one that does what I want. I login, can add email subscribers or edit my articles. I looked into Joomla and some other CMS systems but they do so much more than I need right now I just want something super simple. I just need a push in the direction of a good method for doing it this way.

Comment: There are millions of ways to do this. One way--think [CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete). Add button and form to add image, checkboxes and button to remove images, button and form to edit image properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this tutorial in the link: http://www.elated.com/articles/cms-in-an-afternoon-php-mysql/
There you can see a page named "editArticle.php". It is for edit article in the CMS. You can implement like. This will be helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks, thats a very helpful link, just what I was after.